# How to row.Scan() int32 into Golang gRPC protobuf Enum field?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-go

```
// agent.proto

message Agent {
    Permission permission = 1;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp born_time = 2;

    message Permission {
        Type type = 1;

        enum Type {
            KILLNONE = 0;
            KILLALL = 1;
            DANCE = 2;
        }
   }
}
```

Then scanning SQL row into agent protobuf struct:

```
// main.go

var a proto.Agent

.....

... row.Scan(&a.Permission.Type,...)
```

That permission type is stored as simple MariaDB INT() `value = 0` for default type. So, i can't scan it directly. So i made temp struct where `Type int32` and scaned row into that temp struct after what tried to map temp struct fields to protobuf struct, but with no luck.
Similar issues i had when want to scan MariaDB string values into []byte type fields but i solved that with my temp struct `[]byte(tmp.UUID)`.

What is common patterns to scan database ROW (single row) into protubuf message when non-standard protobuf field types are used?

EDIT: Does there should be some additional `0` value handling?

Answer (score 2):

I usually work with Go types within the business domain, and use adapters to convert to/from the protobuf type.

```
// Role represents a set of permissions
type Role struct {
    KILLNONE = iota
    KILLALL
    DANCE
}

// Permission represents a set of agent permissions
type Permission struct {
    Role Role
}

// ToProto converts a Permission Go type to a protobuf Permission
func (p Permission) ToProto() (proto.Permission) {
    pb := proto.Permission{}
    // assign p's properties to proto's respective properties
    // with necessary type conversions.
    ...
    return pb
}
```

The protobuf examples usually show working with the protobuf types directly, but it seems like adapters are more common in the field.